# How to easily initialize a new object with all values null using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, insert, sqlalchemy

I have a database table with about 15 columns, and I'm using sqlalchemy to access the database. If I want to create a new row to add to the database table, and I want the values of every column (except the id) to be null, is there an easier and more elegant way to do this rather than doing:

```
new_object = table(col1 = None, col2 = None, col3 = None....) //all the way until column 15
```

The error I get when I only give the value of the id and no other parameters is as follows:

```
"TypeError: __init__() missing 15 required positional arguments:"...
```

and then it lists the 15 parameters I didn't assign values to.

Comment: Do you have column defaults on any of them (except the id, which I assume to be of `serial` type.

Comment: I don't, I also didn't create the actual database tables so I unfortunately can't edit them

Comment: You don't need to edit them. *No* default plays into your hands.

Comment: So how can I do this using Sqlalchemy? Because each of my mapped classes have an '__init__', doing something like: 'new_object = table(id = 4)' will result in an error because I haven't assigned values to the other parameters

Comment: The verbatim *error message* of said error should be in your question. That might help to clarify. With a serial column you would not provide a value for the id column ...

Comment: Well actually the id column isn't serial so I do want to provide a value. The error I get when I only give the value of the id and no other parameters is as follows: 

"TypeError: __init__() missing 15 required positional arguments:"... and then it lists the 15 parameters I didn't assign values to

Comment: I edited your question with that - basic information should always go into the question, not be hidden in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The [`INSERT` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) fills all columns of a table that are no mentioned explicitely with their respective column default. If none has been defined, `NULL` is the default default (sic!).

Plus, you can instruct Postgres to insert the column default with the key word `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING id;
```

Should do what you are after and return the newly created `id`.
Not sure how to translate this to your brand of ORM.